# ASP.NET MVC deployment to IIS 5/6 with Virtual Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an asp.net MVC App that I want to deploy to IIS 5 and/or 6 using a Virtual Directory.

I have already performed the wildcard routing, but I have a problem with relative paths.

Imagine I have created a virtual directory called myApp.

After deploying I can go to http://localhost/myApp and am greeted by the index page.  My index page has a link defined as `<a href="/Employees">Employees</a>.`  Clicking on this navigates to 
`http://localhost/Employees` which results in a 404 error.

I would like it to navigate to `http://localhost/myApp/Employees` instead, but I would prefer it if I didn't have to code the virtual directory name into my project.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Html.ActionLink to generate your hyperlinks rather than creating them directly, I think that'll sort it for you. Alternatively, use ./Employees which should get you where you want to go.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Url.Content`

```
<a href="<%= Url.Content("~/Employees") %>">Employees</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an absolute reference: instead of `'/Employees'`, just use `'Employees'` without the `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Url rewriting can help you to solve the problem. I've implemented solution allowing to deploy MVC application at any IIS version even when virtual hosting is used.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/iis-aspnet-url-rewriting.aspx