# ASP.NET MVC Links result in 404 Errors after Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url.action

I have deployed an ASP.NET MVC application following the article *[How to: Deploy an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410407.aspx)*. The index page for the app pulls up correctly rendering images, loading JavaScript and CSS. Unfortunately, none of the links work. I thought this Stack Overflow question *[ASP.NET MVC deployment to IIS 5/6 with Virtual Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211646/asp-net-mvc-deployment-to-iis-5-6-with-virtual-directory)* would solve my issue but to no avail.

Presently, I am attempting to link using this method:

```
<a id="Remove-Sk-<%= item.Sk %>" href=
   "<%= Url.Action("Inactivate", "Item", new { id=item.Sk }) %>"
   class="cboxelement">
```

Which renders

```
<a id="Remove-Sk-113103" href="/app/Item/Inactivate/113103"
   class="cboxelement">
```

Clicking on the rendered link above results in a **404 Error** at:

```
https://dev-env/app/Item/Inactivate/113103
```

This link looks as I would expect it to. What have I done wrong? Is there a configuration issue I am missing?

Comment: You say that the links don't work but then you go on to say that they look correct after clicking on them. Please elaborate on what is incorrect. What are the symptoms that there is something wrong? Are you getting a 404 after clicking?

Comment: @Ray thanks for the question I've modified the question to better reflect the issue. Thank you for asking me to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have deployed to IIS6, have you added the necessary wildcard mappings? This problem manifests itself as 404 errors. You wouldn't see them on your local workstation if you are using IIS7+ or the ASP.NET Development Web Server.

[This](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/) article will help you if this is the issue.